# Running async processes in node.js on multiple cores

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, child-process

Using the `async` and `child_process` modules, I can create true "parallel" processing. My question is, how can I ensure that it is running on multiple cores?

```
var cp = require('child_process');
var async = require('async');

async.parallel([

    function(callback){
        console.log('1');
        var k = cp.fork('./doOther.js',['01']); //how can I ensure the child process k runs on a different core than this process?
        k.on('message',function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            callback();
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('2');
        var k = cp.fork('./doOther.js',['02']); //how can I ensure the child process k runs on a different core than this process?
        k.on('message',function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            callback();
        });
    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('3');
        var k = cp.fork('./doOther.js',['03']); //how can I ensure the child process k runs on a different core than this process?
        k.on('message',function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            callback();
        });

    },
    function(callback){
        console.log('4');
        var k = cp.fork('./doOther.js',['04']); //how can I ensure the child process k runs on a different core than this process?
        k.on('message',function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            callback();
        });

    }

],function(){

    console.log('done.');
    process.exit(0);

});
```

The above script interacts with IPC (inter-process comm) with this script:

```
//doOther.js, a simple script that interacts with the script above

    process.on('message', function(m) {
        console.log('CHILD got message:', m);
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        process.send({ foo: process.argv[2] });
    },1000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice a pattern in the array of your `async.parallel` call? All the functions are the same except for a single number.

And, judging by the repeated comment for each function, you just copied the first version of the function and changed that one number.

You should create a loop that pushes functions into the array, changing that single number each time.

```
for(var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    array.push(function(callback) {
        console.log(i + 1);
        var k = cp.fork('./doOther.js',['0' + (i + 1)]);
        k.on('message',function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
            callback();
        });
    }
}
```

As another tip, if you aren't going to use `k` again, don't store `cp.form(...,...);` in a variable; just continue the `.on` stuff that you were doing to the `k` but to the `cp.form(...,...)`.

That would look like this:

```
cp.fork('./doOther.js', ['0' + (i + 1)]).on('message', function(msg) {
    console.log(msg)
    callback();
});
```

---

Other than that, I'm not too familiar with `node.js` and what a core is, so I can't help you on that part.

Comment: cores just means CPU

Comment: can we increase loop count upto 5000 or more to fork cp?